# ArrayList Generics: subclass

Tags: java, generics, arraylist

Why Statement 1 is valid even though Statement 2 is invalid. I can understand the reason of invalidity of Statement 2, but why is the same principle not applicable in Statament 1?

```
import java.util.*;

public class CollectionTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ArrayList<ObjectB> test = new ArrayList<ObjectA>(); //statement 1

        ObjectB B = new ObjectA("aaa");//statement 2
    }
}

class ObjectA
{
    String a;
    ObjectA(String str) { 
        a = str;
    }
}

class ObjectB extends ObjectA
{
    String b;
    ObjectB(String str) {
        super(str);
        b = str;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're comparing two (invalid) different thing. If you want to do the analogy, you should define your array list this way: `ArrayList<ObjectB> test = new ArrayList<ObjectB>();`

Answer (score 1):

Both are invalid. If you try to run this you'll get compiler errors. You cannot assign a sub-class reference to super-class object. You can only assign a super-class reference to a sub-class object like `ObjectA a = new ObjectB()`; Also when it comes to generics, rules are more strict. The type that you pass on the left hand side should match with the type on the right hand side like below.

```
ArrayList<ObjectB> test1 = new ArrayList<ObjectB>(); // valid
```

(or)

```
ArrayList<ObjectA> test2 = new ArrayList<ObjectA>();  // valid
```

If you try to apply the earlier rule of super-class reference to sub-class object, it will throw an error in case of generics.

```
ArrayList<ObjectA> test = new ArrayList<ObjectB>(); // error
```

If you actually want a list of sub-class objects to a reference of super-class, you can do that by using `extends` keyword.

```
ArrayList<? extends ObjectA> test = new ArrayList<ObjectB>(); // valid
ArrayList<? extends ObjectA> test = new ArrayList<ObjectA>(); // valid
```

`? extends ObjectA` anything means you can have any object that either extends `ObjectA` (if it's a class) or that implements `ObjectA` (if it's an interface) on the RHS.

Answer (score 0):

This is because generics are not reified in Java, they are removed at compilation. Statement 1 is invalid but in a more lenient case translates into `ArrayList`. Statement 2 has a strong type with a relation of "all `ObjectB`s are `ObjectA`s but not all `ObjectA`s are `ObjectB`s." This is similar to "not all animals are dogs but all dogs are animals."